# Horizontal tree in TikZ picture, LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is what I have:

[image]

1) How to make sure that the words don't break and are on the same line?

2) How to highlight the lower right box "Sub-sub-sub-total2 80,000" by making the box bolder or circular, and text bolder too?

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}% cfr added this as the code fails to compile otherwise
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.75in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=0.75]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
    {thick, draw,
        edge from parent fork right},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1.5in,text width=1in, align=center},grow'=right}
\Tree 
[. {Total \\ 500,000} 
[.{Sub-total1 \\ 250,000}
]
[. {Sub-total2 \\ 250,000}
[.{Sub-sub-total1 \\ 50,000} ]
[.{Sub-sub-total2 \\ 200,000} 
[.{Sub-sub-sub-total1 \\ 120,000} ]
[.{Sub-sub-sub-total2 \\ 80,000} ]
]
] 
]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

P.S. And actually, I find this diagram I created quite ugly. I think there is a lot of unused space between the boxes. Can you help me make it compact and easy to read? Thank you.

Comment: Line breaking doesn't occur in nodes by default, in this case it happens because you've set `text width` for all the nodes in the trees.

Comment: Please check that your code compiles before posting it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are open to using `forest`, it can easily do what you want. Forest is a TikZ-based package dedicated to drawing trees. In particular, it is designed to produce (optionally but by default) extremely compact trees. It runs through multiple cycles, first typesetting the nodes, then packing them, then calculating their locations and only drawing the tree when all the calculations are complete. It is also extremely flexible and powerful.

In this case, you can simply allow Forest to figure out the width needed for the nodes and the spacing between them required for a compact but attractive-looking tree.

The `edges` library provides the `forked edges` option similar to the `trees` library's `edge from parent forked ...`. TikZ options can freely be used to style the tree.

To use the `edges` library, we can just pass it as a package option.

```
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
```

Then we can use `forked edges` to style the tree.

```
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
```

We also want to change the default direction of growth from the default southwards to eastwards. We can use `grow'=0` for this (the `'` just stops the change altering the order in which the children are drawn). We want our changes to apply to the whole tree, so we use `for tree={...}`.

```
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
```

We want each node to use `draw` and we want the text to be centred.

```
    draw,
    align=c,
```

I suggest using sans for the text of the nodes. While it is a mistake to overuse sans, it often works well in diagrams, especially quite compact ones.

```
    font=\sffamily,
```

I think that rounding the corners of the nodes borders also makes the tree a little prettier, without being in any way fussy.

```
    rounded corners,
  },
```

Obviously, this is all optional and can easily be omitted if you prefer.

The `highlight` style is defined for easy highlighting of nodes.

```
  highlight/.style={
    thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries
  }
  [{Total\\500,000}
```

If you only need this for one node, you may prefer to add the options directly. I tend to create styles at the drop of the proverbial hat on the grounds that I might apply them more generally and to keep things tidy.

Then we just let Forest do its thing ...

[image: Forest tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    align=c,
    font=\sffamily,
    rounded corners,
  },
  highlight/.style={
    thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries
  }
  [{Total\\500,000}
    [{Sub-total1\\250,000}
    ]
    [{Sub-total2\\250,000}
      [{Sub-sub-total1\\50,000}]
      [{Sub-sub-total2\\200,000}
        [{Sub-sub-sub-total1\\120,000}]
        [{Sub-sub-sub-total2\\80,000}, highlight]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Code for Forest v.1

The above code will work with current Forest. If you only have version 1 and cannot update, you will get a compilation error and will need the following code instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}% for version 1
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    align=c,
    font=\sffamily,
    rounded corners,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  highlight/.style={
    thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries
  }
  [{Total\\500,000}
    [{Sub-total1\\250,000}
    ]
    [{Sub-total2\\250,000}
      [{Sub-sub-total1\\50,000}]
      [{Sub-sub-total2\\200,000}
        [{Sub-sub-sub-total1\\120,000}]
        [{Sub-sub-sub-total2\\80,000}, highlight]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: version 1 version]

Comment: This one is very good, looks very natural, thank you!

Comment: Forest is neat once you get used to it ;).

Comment: Hi again, may you please provide an alternative that doesn't rely on the edges library too? Thank you.

Comment: @Olga Please see edit above.

Comment: Hi cfr, the code returns empty arrows and some figures scattered randomly on the document. I have a screenshot, not sure where to post it in order for you to see.

Comment: @Olga I don't know why that would be. I used version 1 of Forest to produce the screen shot in my edit and the tree doesn't even use arrows, so it seems a bit odd. Can you post your screen shot and the code you used to produce it in [this chat room]? (It says it is for Forest 2 but I think it will be fine there. There isn't a room for Forest 1 and there doesn't really seem to be any need to create one.)

Comment: how do you incorporate labeling into the forest figure with an in-text reference (similar to \label{fig:a} in the figure environment?

Comment: @Olga You can put the Forest tree inside a `figure` environment and then say `\caption{My Forest tree}\label{fig:myforesttree}` in exactly the same way as you would for any other diagram or figure.

Answer (score 4):

For example (`\mbox`es are unnecessary if text width is large enough. Now text width=1.5in (was 1in)):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.75in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=0.75]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
    {thick, draw,
%        edge from parent fork right
},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1.5in,text width=1.5in, align=center},grow'=right}
\Tree 
[. {Total \\ 500,000} 
[.{Sub-total1 \\ 250,000}
]
[. {Sub-total2 \\ 250,000}
[.{\mbox{Sub-sub-total1} \\ 50,000} ]
[.{\mbox{Sub-sub-total2} \\ 200,000} 
[.{\mbox{Sub-sub-sub-total1} \\ 120,000} ]
[.\node[draw, ultra thick]{{\mbox{\textbf{Sub-sub-sub-total2}} \\ \textbf{80,000}}}; ]
]
] 
]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we have more space between the text and the borders?

Comment: @Olga If left and right borders, simply increase text width in `node/.style`. The value 1.5in chosen by me is (near) minimal to include all texts.

Comment: I mean the upper and lower borders.

Comment: @Olga The easy way is to add struts, e.g. `[.{\mbox{\strut Sub-sub-total1} \\ \strut 50,000} ]`. You can alse set, say, `inner distance=2mm` in `node/.style` which is quicker.

Comment: What provides `inner distance`? That isn't standard PGF/TikZ, is it?

Comment: @Olga You can change `inner ysep` to increase the distance from the text to the upper and lower borders. Or you can set `text height`, `text depth` or `minimum height`, depending on what exactly you want the result to be.