# Create horizontal hierarchy tree SmartArt

Tags: tikz-styles, trees

I was trying to draw a horizontal hierarchy SmartArt as shown below. I looked for this forum but I did not find any similar. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Check out these pages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46702/121944, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313050/horizontal-tree-in-tikz-picture-latex, http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for fun and exercises of use the package `forest`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    align=c,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\linespread{0.9}\selectfont,
    text=white,
    inner ysep=2pt,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    edge={semithick,line cap=round},
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=2mm,
  },
  clr/.style={fill=#1}
[Margaret\\xxx,clr=orange
    [Nancy\\xxx,clr=yellow!60!orange
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal
            [Name\\Title,clr=gray]
        ]
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal]
    ]
    [Name\\Title,clr=yellow!60!orange
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal
            [Name\\Title,clr=gray]
        ]
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal
            [Name\\Title,clr=gray]
        ]
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal]
        [Name\\Title,clr=teal]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```